# Where is this line coming from when I run msbuild? ("gitub.com")

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget-package-restore

When I build a project in Visual Studio, I am seeing this odd warning appear in the build output:

`warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://gitub.com'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.`

Notice the 'h' is missing in "gitub.com".

Where is this coming from?

My first thought was some sort of malware. Windows defender and malwarebytes found nothing.

Comment: Sounds like your nuget config file may be broken... have a look at NuGet sources in VS.

Comment: Running `dotnet nuget list source` would be useful too...

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. Here is the output from `dotnet nuget list source`:

`Registered Sources:

  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  GitHub [Enabled]
      http://gitub.com
  3.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
warn : You are running the 'list source' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'GitHub [http://gitub.com]'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.`

^Formatting aside, seems like that's it

Comment: Yup, looks like you just need to fix your nuget config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonSkeet mentioned, the issue is a misconfigured package source in my NuGet config. I just needed to correct the source in NuGet config.

Comment: Glad that this issue doesn't block you anymore. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), as it will benefit other members who get the same or similar issues :)